# an unusual "too" at the end of a sentence

Tags: too-also

x^2=25

**What is the variable equal too?**

I would expect here "to" like this, but instead of it, it's "too".

That makes me confused.

What a role does it play here?

A person who told me this is a New Zealander

Comment: I dunno, looks like an erratum/typo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about a likely typographical error from an unknown source.

Comment: PLEASE, Do not delete the topic. Let me ask the New Zealander to comment on it.

Comment: I've asked her. Her explanation was from "My English teacher taught me this " to "It's obviously wrong. But I still will write like this ". At the end it roll back to : "I didn't a survey. I don't know how kiwis will say it".

Comment: And she also said that she use it because:"It has a lot of answers"

Comment: And she sent me this:[link](https://scontent.fsgn2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/16839653_1779345552083037_1099762532_n.png?oh=cbd7fa587d942575d93655bd3a2ad467&oe=58ADF941)

Answer (score 2):

It's a wrong placement of the word, or a typo. It should be **to**, not too. **Too** does not provide any meaning to this sentence. Too can be at end of a sentence, though. Refer http://grammarist.com/usage/to-too/ for more examples of to and too.